# How to use msw (mocking service worker) with React typescript?

Tags: service-worker, mime, react-typescript, msw

I have installed msw using package.json entry in my react typescript project. And appropriately invoking msw worker start but I constantly get the error

**getWorkerInstance.ts:85 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [MSW] Failed to register the Service Worker:

Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').
`at getWorkerInstance (getWorkerInstance.ts:85:1) at async startWorkerInstance (createStartHandler.ts:31:1) at async SetupWorkerApi.start (setupWorker.ts:188:1)***`
**
Can anyone provide an example source code of how msw works with react typescript ? I got a native react project but that worked? Is msw not supported with React typescript?

Can anyone provide an example source code of how msw works with react typescript ? I got a native react project but that worked? Is msw not supported with React typescript?

Comment: Are you still seeing this issue?